# Email to SMS Solution?

Tags: monitoring

Setting up a monitoring/alerting server and need a better way of sending SMS messages than @vtext.com.  This service by Verizon is simply unreliable.  In my testing, I lose about 30% of my alerts because Verizon just drops/ignores messages for whatever reason.  I heard ATT is the same.  I'm open to either a free SMS service(we're small) or a messaging app like Whatsup.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

In github there are several scripts to do that, if you search mail to SMS. They are not maintained but it is something that you could try.
If you don't want to code, you could use something like zapier.
Another choice to avoid the SMS part is to create a telegram bot

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you resolved this already or not, but you could try [Website monitoring](https://www.simworkflow.com/pages/2aZafZP9mVk5KdfI69w8DP) workflow with [Error handling](https://www.simworkflow.com/pages/1ewaFybmW92ngYI1wWTxUJ) workflow from [SimWorkflow](https://www.simworkflow.com/)?

They'll let you monitor Websites and send notifications via email, SMS and Slack. You can also integrate with WhatsApp API.

Disclosure: I run SimWorkflow. :)